# strange result of standard distribution problem

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I'm new in statics and trying to understand standard distribution which will be showed when ploted

normalized standard distribution example
[image]

So here is my question, I just made random numbers(100 numbers) like this

[52,73,100,32,96,88,92,50,20,44,48,53,32,60,22,15,93,14,50,15,49,49,88,64,84,54,15,71,90,0,80,60,12,1,5,83,12,64,91,72,32,82,79,91,29,74,9,38,58,62,20,12,58,8,99,52,59,97,62,39,24,39,58,26,42,7,17,28,61,19,73,73,14,92,39,53,44,75,34,88,7,76,68,72,51,34,4,42,30,29,41,26,26,82,92,29,67,16,0,94]

and calculated the mean and standard deviation which was 49.45 and 28.6996.
After that I ploted at the screen and found a strange thing that 0(zero) was the minimun of the numbers list but when I put zero in the formula it doesn't come out a very small number like 0.000001. I thought the number should be at the position of the very left side of the picture I pasted it, but It came out like this.

normalized standard distribution result
[image]

And found -50 is the smallest one? Did I did something wrong? Why is zero even bigger than mean-standard deviation*2? I used this formula

Equation 3
[image]

Comment: Did you draw those random numbers from a normal distribution? They look uniformly distributed on {0,1,...100} to me.

Comment: yes, I draw it and the zero was positioned at about Z=-1.7
which was about 95% of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user51547 already commented, the data you provided is uniformly distributed over [0,100]. If you are interested in how to generate normally distributed random variables, one way is the following.

Consider two independent Gaussian random variables $y_1$ and $y_2$ with joint pdf

$P_{y_1 y_2}(y_1,y_2) = \frac{1}{\pi} exp(-y_1^2-y_2^2)$

In polar form, write $y_1 = rcos\theta, y_2 = rsin\theta$ such that the joint pdf becomes $P_{r\theta} = P_r(r)P_{\theta}(\theta)$ where $P_r(r) = 2rexp(-r^2)$and $P_{\theta}(\theta) = 1/(2\pi)$. the polar angle is uniformly distributed so it can be generated through

$\theta = 2\pi x_1$

and $r^2$ is exponentially distributed and can be generated by

$r = \sqrt{-log(x_2)}$

where $X_1,X_2 \sim U(0,1)$. Then, the two Gaussian random variables $Y_1,Y_2 \sim N(0,1/2)$ are given by

$y_1 = \sqrt{-log(x_2)}cos(2\pi x_1), y_2= \sqrt{-log(x_2)}sin(2\pi x_1)$

These are independent of each other.